# How to limit cachegrind files created by xdebug-profiler

Tags: debian, valgrind, cachegrind, xdebug-profiler, webgrind

Is there any way to limit cachegrind files (xdebug profiling output)?
I would like to enable xdebug.profile for debugging whole project (not only trigger), but if someone forget to disable it, I don't want disc to be full.

I didn't find any option like that in [the profiler documentation](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation states ( http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler ) use these settings in your appropriate .ini file - :

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0 
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

Then rather than every single request being profiled, only those with an XDEBUG_PROFILE variable in GET/POST/COOKIE will be profiled.

If you don't want to use the trigger approach, then I suppose you'd need a cron job (or similar) to clean up /tmp (or whatever xdebug.profiler_output_dir is set to) quite frequently.